# Is my setup correct? Enabling ipv6 on a Hetzner server

Tags: ipv6, hetzner

A question about enabling ipv6 on a Hetzner server.

```
ipv6 address:  2a01:4f8:171:1cd3::2
ipv6 subnet is: 2a01:4f8:171:1cd3:: / 64
```

Followed the official Docs: https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/network/net-config-cent-os/#ipv6 (it would help if there was a sample shown as well).

Does this look a correct setup in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:

```
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=2a01:4f8:171:1cd3::2/64
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::1
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=eth0
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES=2a01:4f8:171:1cd3::3 2a01:4f8:171:1cd3::4/64
```

Thank you